# Как правильно работать с composer?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, composer

В своем проекте я хочу использовать twig и boostrap. Установил композер глобально.

Выполнил composer require twig/twig, composer require twbs/bootstrap.
Появилась папка vendor с данными пакетами.
Но папка bootstrap содержит 17 мегабайт файлов. Когда для работы надо 2. Там и исходники и куча всего ненужного.
То есть теперь мой проект содержит "мусор", около 17 мегабайт.

Как вы понимаете, удалить мусор из папки vendor бессмысленно. При следующем composer install с pacagist всё это снова будет загружено. Что то перемещать из папки vendor тоже не имеет смысла - зачем тогда composer, когда я сам всё делаю руками?

Деплоить проект (загружать на хостинг) без папки vendor я не могу - там twig, autoload.php. Также встает вопрос с chmod т.к. boostrap это минимум 755, а давать это на папку vendor неверно.

Как правильно работать с composer?

Comment: Иногда (к сожалению) у некоторых людей на гитхабе в проекте мусор и ничего с этим не сделать. А по хорошему там должно быть разделение на dev - где могут быть примеры использования, юнит тесты и пр  И master версия - где лежит только всё нужное..... посмотрите, возможно вы dev случайно качаете......а если у человека в мастере мусор.....ну....единственный способ - написать скрипт очистки всякого мусора для вашей prod версии. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я делаю свой проект. Мне нужен твиг и бутстрап. Всё это закачал композером.
И теперь в папке бутстрапа у меня куча мусора.

Comment: Спасибо, что поделились этим со мной. Мне что с этой информацией теперь нужно делать?